# How to calculate the coordinates of point C in an isosceles triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, python

*I hope this is not a duplicate but maybe I don't know the right keywords.*

In the following diagram, I know the coordinates of $A=(X_a, Y_a)$ and $B=(X_b, Y_b)$, as well as the distance $h$. What I'm looking for is the coordinates of point $C$. Point $O$ is the midpoint between $A$ and $B$.

[image]

I know that I can use the Pythagorean theorem in order to calculate $AC$ and $BC$, but how would I proceed?

If that helps, I need this for rotating a rectangle using python and openCV.

Comment: This may help: [How to find the third vertex of an isosceles triangle given 2 points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865358/how-to-find-the-third-vertex-of-an-isosceles-triangle-given-2-points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$\vec{A} = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_A \\ y_A \end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\vec{B} = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_B \\ y_B \end{matrix} \right ]$$
Because $\vec{O}$ is halfway between $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$, it is
$$\vec{O} = \frac{\vec{A} + \vec{B}}{2} = \left [ \begin{matrix} \frac{x_A + x_B}{2} \\ \frac{y_A + y_B}{2} \end{matrix} \right ]$$
The unit direction vector from $\vec{A}$ to $\vec{B}$ is $\hat{U}$:
$$\hat{U} = \frac{\vec{B} - \vec{A}}{\left\lVert \vec{B} - \vec{A} \right\rVert} = \left [ \begin{matrix} \frac{x_B - x_A}{\sqrt{(x_B - x_A)^2 + (y_B - y_A)^2}} \\ \frac{y_B - y_A}{\sqrt{(x_B - x_A)^2 + (y_B - y_A)^2}} \end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_U \\ y_U \end{matrix} \right ]$$
The other unit direction vector $\hat{V}$ is $\hat{U}$ rotated 90° degrees clockwise:
$$\hat{V} = \left [ \begin{matrix} y_U \\ - x_U \end{matrix} \right ] $$
Thus, if $\vec{C}$ is at distance $h$ from $\vec{O}$ in the direction of $\hat{V}$, then
$$\vec{C} = \vec{O} + h \hat{V} = \left [ \begin{matrix} \frac{x_A + x_B}{2} + h y_U \\ \frac{y_A + y_B}{2} - h x_U \end{matrix} \right ]$$

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I tried to convert this in python but I don't seem to get the expected coordinates. Is it wrong to consider that vectors can be translated to point coordinates?

Comment: Oh, could it be that it's `xA+xB` instead of `xA+yA` at the very last formula?

Comment: @Phi: Yes, the $x$ component of $\vec{C}$ should be $(x_A + x_B)/2 + h\,y_U$. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate the help!